# Geospatial Canadian Socioeconomic Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, census, canada, economy

I've been working with Canadian statistics data and performing geovisualizations of this data joined to census boundary shapefiles.

Most of the data I've been able to join has been at the level of:

- Provinces/territories
- Health Regions
- Census Division (for a not-so-reliable set of Household-level variables; For those familiar with the 2011 National Household Survey, the limitations are jarring)

I'm curious if there are any socioeconomic data tables available through CANISM or other Canadian statistical agencies for variables such as:

- Self-reported Quality of Health
- Average Income per capita/household
- Educational Attainment
- Cost of Living Indicators
- etc.

that can be **geospatially organized** (ie: GIS-formattable) at a very fine resolution (e.g. Census Dissemination Areas/Blocks, Postal Codes, Industry Canada Service Areas)

**Update:**

I've been able to find the CHASS database (http://dc.chass.utoronto.ca/index.html) which is an intermediary data product compiled from statistical data for all census across geographic regions. This data is only open to researchers at specific Canadian universities.

Does anyone know of a similar project, but openly available to unassociated researchers?

Comment: where would i find simply canadian income data?

Comment: The typical convention for StackExchange is to search through the questions on top and, if the question hasn't been asked, ask it.

To answer your question, the best place to get raw and processed socioeconomic data for Canada is the Statistics Canada entry on [Income in Canada](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/subjects/income_pensions_spending_and_wealth) or the [CANSIM tables](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/type/data). Best of luck!